# Convert a dictionary of sets into a set of tuples in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, set, tuples

How can I convert a dictionary, where the values are sets, into a set of tuples of corresponding keys and values, but with a new tuple for every set member.

For example:

```
{'A': {'B', 'C'}, 'B': {'A', 'C'}, 'C': {'A', 'B', 'D'}, 'D': {'C'}}
```

would return something similar to this

```
{('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'A'), ('B', 'C'), ('C', 'A'), ('C', 'B'), ('C', 'D'), ('D', 'C'),}
```

Comment: That output is a *set* of tuples, but yes you could do that. Have you tried anything? What happened?

Comment: I have tried using defaultdict, but i don't think that was the right way to go in this situation

Comment: Well no, if you're trying to end up with *not* a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just use a set comprehension with a nested loop to produce the product (each key with each of the contained elements of each set referenced):

```
{(k, v) for k, values in d.items() for v in values}
```

Demo:

```
>>> d = {'A': {'B', 'C'}, 'B': {'A', 'C'}, 'C': {'A', 'B', 'D'}, 'D': {'C'}}
>>> {(k, v) for k, values in d.items() for v in values}
{('B', 'A'), ('D', 'C'), ('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C'), ('C', 'B'), ('C', 'D'), ('A', 'C'), ('C', 'A')}
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(_)
{('A', 'B'),
 ('A', 'C'),
 ('B', 'A'),
 ('B', 'C'),
 ('C', 'A'),
 ('C', 'B'),
 ('C', 'D'),
 ('D', 'C')}
```